# некорректно работает условие

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть две формы ввода `input type='text'` для ввода ставки и бюджета.
Проверяю, чтобы ставка не была выше бюджета

```
if(advs.cost.value > advs.total_cost.value){
     alert('Ставка выше вашего бюджета');
}
```

если `cost = 1` , а `total_cost = 10` - все ок, а если  `cost = 2,3,4 и т.д` , то ошибка. Почему так происходит?

Спасибо

Comment: Ты сравниваешь строки и не числа. Строки сравниваются в лексикографическом порядке. 2<10, но '2'>'10'

Comment: понял . Спасибо!